# How to access session in socket(Node.js)

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I am using express and socket.io for developing a random chat application.Now i need to access session in socket event.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){  
  socket.on('sendMessage',function(data){
   session.userId //senderId
 }); 
});
```

session is available in request object but is there is easy way to access session in socket events.I have checked these questions but the answers are quite complicated and old.

> [How to share sessions with Socket.IO 1.x and Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25532692/3143384)
>
> [socket.io and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4641053/3143384)
>
> [How to get session id with Socket.IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19082693/3143384)

please share if any new way is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way for this..

If you're using socket.io >= 1.0 here is a [simple module](https://github.com/xpepermint/socket.io-express-session)

```
var ios = require('socket.io-express-session');
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
io.use(ios(Session));
```

then

```
var sess = socket.handshake.session;
sess.userId
```

As simple as that.

reference [session.socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session.socket.io)